# Facebook Realtime API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I believe to have Facebook realtime notifications set up correctly but don't receive any notifications. Any ideas?

[image: Realtime call back URL setup]

And here my callback.php

```
define('VERIFY_TOKEN', 'SECRET');                                    
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];                             


if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' && $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN) {
   echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
} else if ($method == 'POST') {

   if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE'] ) ) {
    $post_body = file_get_contents("php://input");

    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE'] == "sha1=" . hash_hmac('sha1', $post_body, VERIFY_TOKEN)) {

        $object = json_decode($post_body, true);

        file_put_contents('/PATH_TO_FOLDER/updates.txt', $object, FILE_APPEND);

        }       
    }
}
```

I'm not getting anything and the .txt file is not created.

Comment: Can you put a log statement right at the top, so you'll know it's being called at least. Debugging callbacks can be a little bit tricky because you don't see the output.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen, cheers for that. Doesn't seem to get called at all. FB should ping the callback URL on any changes on the page's feed but not happening.

Comment: Have you set up the page to notify your app specifically as well? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime

Comment: Note for future readers: In the hash_hmac() call, you want to use your "app secret", not the callback token.  This is the secret you find under general app settings, not under the payments area where you set the callback URL.